# Когда нужно использовать memcache в PHP проектах?

Tags: php, memcached

Здравствуйте!

Есть вопрос: когда нужно использовать memcache вместо файлового кэша?

В Интернете ничего толкового не нашел. Знаю, что доступ к ОЗУ быстрее, чем ПЗУ. Но также знаю, что memcache работает через сетевой интерфейс, а это может все плюсы ОЗУ свести на нет.

В общем, жду ответы. Заранее спасибо! =)

Comment: > Есть вопрос: когда нужно использовать memcache вместо файлового кэша?

Всегда, когда есть такая возможность.

Comment: @sergey_pogorelov_93, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Всегда, но есть но:

1. Не надо хранить там очень большие файлы (надеюсь, вы не из google).
2. Не надо хранить там данные, которые придеться очень (очень) часто обновлять.
3. Данные, которые должны быть на 100% актуальные.
4. Данные, которые не сохранены на диск (а мы боимся их потерять).